# CSS - Reponsive Bootstrap Carousel in SharePoint Web Part

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, carousel, responsive

I just want to preface this with while Bootstrap carousel is being used, it's been greatly customized (though not by me) to be used in a SharePoint web part. I feel like that's important to note since there's potentially a lot going on in this particular environment that does/could affect the CSS.

That being said, I'm having troubles making the Bootstrap carousel responsive.  I moved a lot of the styles around, but this is the latest iteration:

```
#Carousel { 
max-width: 400px; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 926px) {

#Carousel { 
position: relative; 
width: 100%; 
height: 0; 
padding-bottom: 40%; 
}

#Carousel .carousel-indicators, #jbCarousel .carousel-inner, #jbCarousel .control-container { 
position absolute; 
width: 100%; 
}

}
```

I want the #Carousel container to be at most 400px; I tried to keep its aspect ratio, too.  This doesn't work, what happens is that it stays 400px no matter how the window is resized.  And since the children I set above are at `width: 100%`, they're also set at 400px, so nothing actually changes in size.

Comment: Try changing 400px to %.

Comment: @Vaibhav Thank you, but 400% would make it much larger than the parent container, which isn't what I wanted.  What the issue was that the parent container was a div that was forced to act a table (`display: table;`) and that caused everything under it to be inflexible when resizing the screen, etc.  I fixed it by adding 'table-layout: fixed;` to the parent and this allowed all the descendants to be responsive and not overflow.

Comment: I didn't mean 400%. I meant u keep 100% or any % that suits your layout. Thanks for posting solution as well.